# Bash kill background commands block

Tags: bash, shell, kill-process

I have some bash script where I put a block of commands in background and then want to kill them

```
#!/bin/bash
{ sleep 117s; echo "test"; } &
ppid=$!
# do something important
<kill the subprocess somehow>
```

I need to find a way to kill the subprocess so if it still sleeps then it stops sleeping and "test" won't be printed. I need to do it automatically in the script, so I can't use another shell.

What I already tried so far:

1. `kill $ppid` - doesn't kill sleep at all (with -9 flag too), sleep ppid becomes 1 but test won't be printed
2. `kill %1` - the same result as above
3. `kill -- -$ppid` - it complains `kill: (-30847) - No such process` (and the subprocess is still here)
4. `pkill -P $ppid` - test has been printed

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command group in its own sub-shell. Use set -m to run the sub-shell in its own process group. Kill the process group

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
( sleep 117s; echo "test"; ) &
ppid=$!
# do something important
kill -- -$ppid
```

Comment: Could you please explain difference between `{...}` and `(...)` in case of background task?

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin, good point. In the case of a background task both run in a sub-shell

Answer (score 2):

Just changue your code for:

```
{ sleep 117s && echo "test"; } &
```

From `bash` `man`:

> command1 && command2
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status
>   of zero.

Demo:

```
$ { sleep 117s; echo "test"; } &
[1] 48013
$ pkill -P $!
-bash: line 102: 48014 Terminated              sleep 117s
$ test

[1]+  Done                    { sleep 117s; echo "test"; }



$ { sleep 117s && echo "test"; } &                                                                                                      
[1] 50763
$ pkill -P $!                                                                                                      
-bash: line 106: 50764 Terminated              sleep 117s
```

Comment: It works, but looks like a workaround. Actually, this way won't work if I have to handle non-zero exit codes. 1_CR's solution is better, but anyway, thank you!